# Is there any way to further tune the following query?

Tags: mysql, spring, performance, query-optimization

Also, can you review whether the following decision-making process is sufficiently logical?

1. The execution time for the query below is about 100ms using postman.
2. However, when there is a certain amount of traffic, the response time is found to exceed 10 seconds.(most of the time was spent on getConnection()).
   I also tried adjusting the connection pool size, but the results were similar
3. I found out that the CPU usage and memory usage of the database server were high.
4. Other APIs used less CPU/memory of the database server, so the getConnection() time was less.
5. We assumed that the API used a lot of server resources and considered scaling up, but it did not significantly help improve server performance.
6. So this time, we are going to try to scale out.

Even though the query below consumes a lot of memory/cpu, I'm not sure how to optimize it.

```sql
Hibernate: 
    select
        store0_.store_id as col_0_0_,
        store0_.name as col_1_0_,
        store0_.address as col_2_0_,
        store0_.avg_review_rating as col_3_0_,
        store0_.like_count as col_4_0_ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    inner join
        category category1_ 
            on store0_.category_id=category1_.category_id 
    left outer join
        store_keyword storekeywo2_ 
            on store0_.store_id=storekeywo2_.store_id 
    left outer join
        keyword keyword3_ 
            on storekeywo2_.keyword_id=keyword3_.keyword_id 
    where
        store0_.status=? 
        and ?=? 
        and keyword3_.name=? 
        and ?=? 
        and (
            store0_.name like ? escape '!'
        ) 
    order by
        store0_.avg_review_rating desc limit ?
Hibernate: 
    select
        store1_.store_id as col_0_0_ 
    from
        store_keyword storekeywo0_ 
    inner join
        store store1_ 
            on storekeywo0_.store_id=store1_.store_id 
    inner join
        keyword keyword2_ 
            on storekeywo0_.keyword_id=keyword2_.keyword_id 
    where
        store1_.status=? 
        and ?=? 
        and keyword2_.name=? 
        and ?=? 
        and (
            store1_.name like ? escape '!'
        )
Hibernate: 
    select
        store0_.store_id as col_0_0_,
        storeimage1_.url as col_1_0_,
        keyword3_.name as col_2_0_ 
    from
        store store0_ 
    left outer join
        image storeimage1_ 
            on store0_.store_id=storeimage1_.store_id 
    left outer join
        store_keyword storekeywo2_ 
            on store0_.store_id=storekeywo2_.store_id 
    inner join
        keyword keyword3_ 
            on storekeywo2_.keyword_id=keyword3_.keyword_id 
    where
        store0_.store_id in (
            ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?
        )
```

```java
 @Override
    public Page<StoreResponseWithKeyword> findStoresByCondition(Pageable pageable, String category, String keyword, String location, String storeName) {
        List<StoreResponseWithKeyword> storeQuery = null;
        int count=0;
        if(!keyword.isBlank()){
            storeQuery = jpaQueryFactory
                    .select(
                            Projections.constructor(
                                    StoreResponseWithKeyword.class,
                                    store.storeId,
                                    store.name,
                                    store.address,
                                    store.avgReviewRating,
                                    //keywordlist
                                    //image.url,
                                    store.likeCount
                            ))
                    .from(store)
                    .where(store.status.eq(StoreStatus.APPROVED))
                    .where(
                            categoryEq(category),
                            keywordContain(keyword),
                            addressContain(location),
                            storeNameContain(storeName)
                    )
                    .innerJoin(store.category, QCategory.category)
                    .leftJoin(store.storeKeywordList, storeKeyword)
                    .leftJoin(storeKeyword.keyword, QKeyword.keyword)
                    .orderBy(createOrderSpecifiers(pageable))
                    .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                    .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
                    .fetch();
            count = jpaQueryFactory
                    .select(store.storeId)
                    .from(storeKeyword)
                    .where(store.status.eq(StoreStatus.APPROVED))
                    .where(
                            categoryEq(category),
                            keywordContain(keyword),
                            addressContain(location),
                            storeNameContain(storeName)
                    )
                    .innerJoin(storeKeyword.store, store)
                    .innerJoin(storeKeyword.keyword, QKeyword.keyword)
                    .fetch().size();
        }else{
            storeQuery = jpaQueryFactory
                    .select(
                            Projections.constructor(
                                    StoreResponseWithKeyword.class,
                                    store.storeId,
                                    store.name,
                                    store.address,
                                    store.avgReviewRating,
                                    store.likeCount
                            ))
                    .from(store)
                    .where(store.status.eq(StoreStatus.APPROVED))
                    .where(
                            categoryEq(category),
                            addressContain(location),
                            storeNameContain(storeName)
                    )
                    .innerJoin(store.category, QCategory.category)
                    .orderBy(createOrderSpecifiers(pageable))
                    .offset(pageable.getOffset())
                    .limit(pageable.getPageSize())
                    .fetch();

            count = jpaQueryFactory
                    .select(store.storeId)
                    .from(store)
                    .where(store.status.eq(StoreStatus.APPROVED))
                    .where(
                            categoryEq(category),
                            keywordContain(keyword),
                            addressContain(location),
                            storeNameContain(storeName)
                    )
                    .fetch().size();
        }


        List<Long> storeIds = storeQuery.stream().map(StoreResponseWithKeyword::getStoreId).collect(Collectors.toList());

        // Image URL 및 Keyword 한 번에 가져오기
        List<Tuple> combinedData = jpaQueryFactory
                .select(store.storeId, image.url, QKeyword.keyword.name)
                .from(store)
                .leftJoin(store.storeImageList, image)
                .leftJoin(store.storeKeywordList, storeKeyword)
                .leftJoin(storeKeyword.keyword, QKeyword.keyword)
                .where(store.storeId.in(storeIds))
                .fetch();

        Map<Long, String> storeIdToImageUrl = new HashMap<>();
        Map<Long, Set<String>> storeIdToKeywordNames = new HashMap<>();

        for (Tuple tuple : combinedData) {
            Long storeId = tuple.get(store.storeId);
            String imageUrl = tuple.get(image.url);
            String keywordName = tuple.get(QKeyword.keyword.name);

            storeIdToImageUrl.putIfAbsent(storeId, imageUrl);

            if (keywordName != null) {
                storeIdToKeywordNames.computeIfAbsent(storeId, k -> new HashSet<>()).add(keywordName);
            }
        }

        for (StoreResponseWithKeyword response : storeQuery) {
            String storedImageUrl = storeIdToImageUrl.getOrDefault(response.getStoreId(), "");
            response.setStoreImageUrl(storedImageUrl);

            Set<String> keywordList = storeIdToKeywordNames.getOrDefault(response.getStoreId(), Collections.emptySet());
            response.setKeywordList(new ArrayList<>(keywordList));
        }


        return new PageImpl<>(storeQuery, pageable, count);
    }
```

```java
public class StoreResponseWithKeyword {
    private Long storeId;
    private String storeName;
    private String address;
    private Double avgScore;
    private List<String> keywordList = new ArrayList<>();
    private String storeImageUrl;
    private Long likeCount;

}
```

Comment: Could you please share the query plan, the ddl for all tables and indexes involved, and the query itself. All in plain text as an update to your question

Comment: If `getConnection` is the culprit tuning the query won't help. It means you either have leaking connections, or your connection pool has too little connections. One thing to improve is to write query instead of 3 to retrieve the data.

Comment: `and  ?=?` -- What is likely to be substituted?  (This matters in considering Optimizations!)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that table `xx` has `PRIMARY KEY(xx_id)`, I recommend adding the following composite indexes.  (Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` if my assumption is wrong.)

```
store:  INDEX(status, name)
image:  INDEX(store_id,  url)
store_keyword:  INDEX(store_id,  keyword_id)
keyword:  INDEX(name, keyword_id)
```

Performance red flags:

`LIKE`

- `store1_.name like ? escape '!'` -- When the string (for `?`) has a *leading* wildcard (such as `%`), the index cannot be used.
- A non-leading wildcard can be partially optimized.
- If `?` is replaced by a string without any wildcards, it is optimized like `=`.  Above, `(status, name)` is a single index that does the best it can for all 3 cases.

Multiple tables:

- A `WHERE` clause referencing more than one table, such as your first 2 queries -- The Optimizer cannot tell which table to look at first; when it makes the wrong choice, the query will be slower.  (There is no viable workaround for this issue.)
- `join category category1_`, but `category` is never used.  It will, however, look into category anyway to discover that there is some category.  If there is always a "category", then this `JOIN` is a waste of time.  Changing to `LEFT JOIN` makes the category optional, but the Optimizer may [depending on version] be too dumb to avoid looking into the table anyway.

LEFT

- `left outer join keyword ... WHERE keyword ...` -- This turns into an `INNER JOIN` (not a 'performance' issued, but a confusion to the reader.)

Add the suggested indexes and consider my comments on `category`; if you still have performance issues, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each table and `SHOW TABLE STATUS`.  There may be some more-subtle issues (such as datatype inconsistencies.)